# What exactly did I do to get the Loremaster achievement?

Tags: achievements, moon-hunters

I got the Loremaster achievement on my latest playthrough, but I'm not exactly sure what unlocked it. The description says:

> Research each aspect of the Moon Goddess

What exactly is this referring to? It was my fifth playthrough, and at that point I had played each of the first four classes (and the Snowdancer), and started from each village once. That said, I might have done other things for all 4 (?) aspects of the Moon Goddess for the first time, like looked at the statues in the villages or something. So I can't really tell what unlocked it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is exactly what you did:

> End the game at least once for each first playable character (Not
>   included: Sun Cultist / Songweaver)

Source on [this Steam guide](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=648432595), first part of "Achievements", down the page.

Edit: as MartinEnder pointed out in the comments below,

> It's worth noting then that only the first player counts towards this.

Comment: It's worth noting then that only the first player counts towards this. The hero I chose on my last playthrough had already been picked by someone else on an earlier co-op playthrough.

Comment: @MartinEnder if I answered your question, could you please mark it as resolved, so it increases Arqade stats on all answered questions?

Comment: Done, I was just waiting for the edit.